# Probability Distribution for Regression PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I am building a regression neural network which predicts a number. I was wondering if there was a way to get a probability distribution for the predicted number. With classification you can get the softmax of the classes you can choose from, and from that you can know how certain the model is of the predicted class. Is there some way you can do this with regression?

Btw. I am using PyTorch.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no probability in regression. It doesn't make any sense.
Because in regression you have infinite output possibilities, so the probability of predicting a single value would be 0.

But, obviously you can discretize your output and your target to make probabilities, but this will basically convert you problem to classification.